# ¿Crear un mapa con indices y un arreglo de objetos?

Tags: java

No se mucho de java y no se como crear un mapa el cual pueda este me retone una estructura de esta manera

```
 [
  "300202" : [
    {"llave":123,"nombre": Martillo},
    {"llave":345,"nombre": Alicate},
    {"llave":12543,"nombre": Martillo}
   ],
  "300123":  [
    {"llave":765,"nombre": Pulsera},
    {"llave":56756,"nombre": Taladro},
    {"llave":34,"nombre": tuerca}
  ]
```

> He Intentado modelar con el siguiente ejemplo algo similar pero al
> darle list.clear o remove me limpia la lista, lo que quiero es que a
> todos los items que correpondan a una llave le haga tipo "PUSH" como
> normalmente se haria en otro lenguaje.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();//Creating arraylist    
    
         HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> people = new HashMap <>();
         
        
        int index = 0;
         
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++ ) {
            
             list.add(index,"Mango"+i);
             System.out.println(list);
            
            if (!people.containsKey("123") && i <= 5) {
                people.put("123", list);
                System.out.println("No está");
            }else{
                if(i <= 5){
                    people.put("123", list);
                    System.out.println("Si está");
                }
            }
            
           if(i == 5){
                index++;
            }
            
            if (!people.containsKey("456") && i > 5) {
                people.put("456", list);
                System.out.println("No está");
            }else{
                if(i > 5){
                    people.put("456", list);
                    System.out.println("Si está");
                }
            }
            
            /*if (!people.containsKey("123")) {
                people.put("123", "");
            }else{
                people.put("123", list);
            }*/
        }
    
    
    System.out.println("Peoples: "+people);
    }
```

Agradecería bastante de su ayuda, aclaro que no se absolutamente nada de java y que si o si necesito trabajar con este lenguaje.

Comment: ¿Investigaste o trataste como realizarlo?, recuerda que es importante David, saludos.

Comment: Si @Jorgesys, lo he intentado, gracias por recordarmelo, saludos

Comment: push es una operación para agregar, por que querrías hacerle un clear?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Gracias por el comentario, como lo menciono no se nada de java, y con lo que he investigado consideré que si lleno la lista y la agrego a la llave los datos ya iban a quedar guardados y una vez hiciera clear iba a guardar nuevos datos para agregarcelos a la nueva llave, saludos

Comment: pon por favor un ejemplo con la primera notación que pusiste del antes y el después

Answer (score 2):

No se si esto es lo que deseas pero aqui te dejo estos ejemplos:

```
//crear un map
HashMap<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();

//crear un listmap
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> people = new ArrayList<>();

//añadir un map a un listmap
list.put("id", "1726");
list.put("name", "tuerca");
people.add((int)0, list);

//borrar llaves
for(int x = 0 ; x < people.size() ; x++){
    if(people.get((int) x).containsKey("id")){
        if(people.get((int) x).get("id").toString().equals("1726")){
            people.remove((int) x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Super, eso era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias